# Reading JSON-LD files with stream reader v.s serialising them to a POCO in ASP.NET Core 3.1 web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

My question is for ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. My goal is to insert a JSON-LD structured data into the header of my web application and I want to do it with the following conditions:

1. dynamically from controller
2. as efficiently as possible
3. Without using a nugget package (I know about Schema.NET)

I generated the JSON-LD files using an online tool from google. I want to see which one of these scenarios are more efficient to insert the data into the html files.

- Method One: reads the json file with stream reader and passes the data as a string to the viewbag
- Method Two: De-serialises the Json file into a POCO when application starts in Stratup.cs. Then Serialises the POCO back into a JSON in the action method.

```
//in Startup.cs for method two only
services.Configure<LocalBusiness>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(LocalBusiness)));
            
//In Controller           
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //methode one: reading the LocalBusiness.Json file and passing the data to viewBag
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"Schema\LocalBusiness.json"))
            {
                string json = await r.ReadToEndAsync();
                ViewBag.JsonLd = json;
            }

            //Method two: passing the content of LocalBusiness.Json to a POCO class in startup.cs 
            //and then calling the data using IOptions<LocalBusiness> in the controller
            //var localBusiness is injected into controller via IOptions<LocalBusiness>
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(localBusiness);
            ViewBag.JsonLd = jsonString;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: so what is your question? would you like to know which one is better? I would suggest you use to model and bind the data to it and pass it to the view from the controller

Comment: Thanks Vivek, yes I want to know which method is better approach. Binding to model or reading from json file directly

Comment: Binding to model is better in your case, because it’s strongly typed.